# Unable to login facebook with fb.login api in Iphone (error code 101 when loading with url )

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am facing a weird issue with iphones

Unable to login facebook with mobile. The `Fb.login` API fails with `error code 101` 
error description (Error-101 when loading url)

Every thing works fine if i try it in any other platform example android,windows the problem persists with the iphone platform whenever i try to login it accepts the facebook id and password and then throws an error 101.

```
FB.init(App ID, Channel File, status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true);
FB.login(function (response) {}(function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk',
        ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
    }
    js = d.createElement('script');
    js.id = id;
    js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you tried already?

Comment: Every thing works fine if i try it in any other platform example android,windows the problem persists with the iphone platform whenever i try to login it accepts the facebook id and password and then throws an error 101.

Comment: FB.init(App ID, Channel File ,status: true,cookie: true,xfbml: true);                                                  FB.login(function (response) {}
    (function (d) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document));